How do I transform a 3-d cloud to a single point in another space
I have a 3-d scan of a cloud of objects (points as far as this is concerned) and wish to compare it to a 3-d scan of a different cloud - both clouds being in standard Euclidean space. When I last looked at such a problem forty years ago (-ish) - I transformed the clouds into another multi-dimensional space where each cloud was shown as a single point.  So - comparing the clouds was by looking at the distance between the points in the new space.  Dozens of clouds in the original space were transformed into the same number of points in the new space and differences could be easily seen.
When I first looked at the problem - someone showed me a book with the approach in it.  I was able to use the approach to computerise the solution.  I can not remember the book nor the approach.  Can anyone help?

The simplest thing to do would be to transform your $3\times n$ dataset into a $3n\times 1$ column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The issue with this (and any similar approach) is that the order of the points would be very important. Are you expecting the points in each cloud to be in the same order?
